# Library or component to do Java-jQuery Object Remoting?

Tags: java, jquery, remoting

... I mean I can write down my own classes that generate JSON but I'd rather not :)

Answer (score 0):

And you are looking for an JSON library? I can recommend [google-gson](http://code.google.com/p/google-gson/) for it